# OpenGL MRT glDrawBuffers() argument numbers and behavior

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, textures, fbo

I have a total of 5 render targets. I use the same shader to write to the first 4, then in a seperate pass write to the last one.

Before calling rendering to the first 4 targets I call:

```
GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1,  GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3};
glDrawBuffers(4, drawBuffers);
```

However, when I call it for second pass and only want to write to the last one, the 5th target, why does the following give strange results?

```
GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4 };
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
```

Why do I have to instead use:

```
GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_NONE, GL_NONE, GL_NONE, GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4 };
glDrawBuffers(5, drawBuffers);
```

Is this simply how glDrawBuffers() works, or is being caused by something else?

EDIT: fixed code with regards Jarrods comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is simply [how `glDrawBuffers` works](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer#Draw_color_buffers). But there's a reason for that.

Fragment shaders write color outputs that map to certain "color numbers". These have *no relation* to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT''i'' numbers. The entire point of `glDrawBuffers` is to map those fragment color numbers to actual buffers in the framebuffer.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawBuffers.xml

The 2nd parameter must be of the type `const GLenum*` i.e. a pointer "to an array of symbolic constants specifying the buffers into which fragment colors or data values will be written".

So just passing `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT4` as the 2nd param is the wrong type. You need to pass a pointer to an array of `GLEnum`.

Comment: Sorry, in my code I actually have it as 1 element array as you said, I was just trying to be more concise in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I find that there's something wrong in glDrawBuffers().
for exmple
tmp = {attement_color0, attachement_color2}
glDrawBuffers(tmp).
in shader:
gl_fragdata[0]=...
gl_fragdata[2]=...

or u can use layout location to define the attments output.
But sometimes, at least in my PC, it does not work. I mean the attachment_color2 does NOT have the exact output.